# How disappear date picker when select any date in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

When I click on input field then a date picker is appeared. After select date it shows in input field but date picker form is not disappear. How to do that . My form code is

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date_of_report">Date Of Report:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="date_of_report2" name="date_of_report" class="input-small datepicker2 " type="date"  />                                                  

    </div>
</div>
```

My script is

```
$('.datepicker2').datepicker('update');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `option` of datepicker and add `autoclose` something like this

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
});
```

see the [documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html) here